# Is there a way to pass html/css options to rails_admin inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin and I'd like to add a few custom styles to my admin section on some inputs. Is there any way to specify additional classes?

Something like:

```
  configure :title, :string do
    css_class 'my-class'
    input_html {:class => 'my-class', :toolbar => 'my-toolbar'}
  end
```

I can't seem to find a comprehensive list of what options are available. I know I can specify `hidden`, `visible`, `ckeditor true`, and one or two other things.

I'm using some additional custom JS and CSS, but I need to be able to specify some CSS classes to make everything work the way I want.

Specifically, I'm using CKEditor, and would like to use multiple toolbars, one simple and one advanced. I've been able to config CKEditor fine, but I can't find a way to have Rails_admin use an alternate toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :html_attributes

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/base.rb#L126

Answer (score 2):

There is also **[css_class](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/base.rb#L31)**. So you could have something like:

```
field :your_field do
  css_class do
    # Be sure to not remove the original class 
    # set by #{self.name}_field
    "#{self.name}_field your_custom_class"
  end
end
```